# Carrying 2L alcohol bought on arrival at dubai duty free in check-in baggage, will I be able to shop duty-free at delhi International Airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india

Carrying 2L alcohol bought on arrival at dubai duty free in check-in baggage, will I be able to shop more 2L duty-free at delhi International Airport?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not whether you can buy more duty free at Delhi, the problem is how much you can import to India. You are only permitted to import 2L of alcohol to India without paying duty on it. If you have more than that you will be charged duty. It doesn't matter that it was bought in a Duty Free shop.